# Displaying multiple videos on Panels locks UI - using Refresh() / Invalidate()

Tags: c#, multithreading, video, ffmpeg, panel

I try to show 32 different videos ( `768 * 532 pixels` and `25 fps`) on an application as two `4x4` displays. Each video is displayed on a `Player` class which has a `Panel` object.
I get the RTP streams from network and converting them to bitmap image using `FFmpeg` and set bitmaps as panel background images and then `Refresh()` the panel.
When the number of displaying videos increases (as 17-18) the UI starts to lock, it is not responding.
Then I use `Invalidate()`, this time UI is not locking, it responds any events even for 32 displays but after 17-18 display it can not catch up refreshing rate (`25fps`). The videos are displayed by skipping some of the frames.
I am setting background images of `Panel`'s and refreshing them in different threads. Do I need to do one refreshing for all panels. Or use another refreshing method?
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you do with old bitmaps? They can be a problem is you aren't disposing them properly as they are consuming system resourses and your application simply runs out of needed amount of memory.

Comment: I preallocate 10 bitmaps for every display and then I use them again and again. Just marshall.Copy new Data to their data